# Allow users to changer the sort order

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

How do allow users to change the order of posts, based on custom fields?

For example :

First custom field: Value1, second custom field: Value2.

In archive page, the posts are presented in order of the value 1 by default, and a filter (links) allows to order them according to the value 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pre_get_posts hook as per the example here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/#comment-2571.  This assumes that your custom fields are stored as post_meta.

Note that you need to be very careful that you are only affecting the query that you want to affect at the time that you want to affect it.  In this example they are checking that they are not in admin, that they only doing events (in your case you want posts) and that it is the main query (not another query that say a widget or some other function is running).    Consider limiting it to the page that you want this to run on or putting the code in the theme template, so that it only runs for that template and not at any other time.

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with this function, but am looking to create a filter to allow users to change the order.

Comment: I assume you mean you still need a way for them to say what order they want?   you need to decide is it something they decide dynamically from the page the see the post archive & the new sort order is only applied for that run OR is it something they specify in settings screen, you save rhe choice and then look it & apply to the filter above?